# change request format sent to dialogflow agent

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

User queries to dialogflow agent through google assistant using voice commands.I want to add some data in that user query. can we change the request parameters sent to agent? If yes, where? The code for google assistant library is in python.

I am working on python 3.5 on raspberry pi 3. I tried modifying event.py file located at google/library/assistant/ . But before the event for ON_RECOGNISING_SPEECH_FINISHED I got response from google assistant.

Comment: What does your call to Dialogflow looks like today?

Comment: I am not able to find it in Google assistant SDK library

Answer (score 1):

No, if you're using the Google Assistant SDK, you interact with the agent as if it was any other Google Assistant surface. There is no way to add additional context that is exclusive to your device.

Comment: ok.. thank you. If you come across any other workaround please let me know.